# Como deletar registro com modal?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou há algum tempo mexendo com ASP.NET e me deparei com um problema que não consigo solucionar. A ideia é somente abrir uma janela modal, clicar na confirmação e excluir um registro.
A ideia desse código é somente para teste, se eu conseguir fazer funcionar desta forma, acredito que consigo adaptar meu código e fazer de uma forma mais inteligente.

Vou anexar os códigos. Estou usando o SweetAlert.

Este é meu Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    _clienteApp.Remove(_clienteApp.GetById(id));
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Este é meu botão de delete:

```
<button id="btn-deletar" data-codigo="@item.ClienteID"  class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash fa-lg"></button>
<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
```

Este é meu JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
function deleteDialog() {
    swal({
        title: "Tem certeza que deseja excluir o registro?",
        text: "Uma vez deletado, é impossível recuperá-lo",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    }).then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $.post("/Clientes/Delete/4");
            swal("Seu registro foi deletado!", {
                icon: "success"


            });
        } else {
            swal("Seu registro não foi deletado");
        }
    });
}
$('#btn-deletar').click(deleteDialog);
```

Comment: Não entendi bem a dúvida. Seu código já não está funcionando?

Comment: Não, a ideia é somente deletar o registro com id 4. O erro ocorre quando eu clico na confirmação de delete "POST http://localhost:63712/Clientes/Delete 500 (Internal Server Error)"